# "The signature for the webhook is not present in the Stripe-Signature header."

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe.net SDK from NuGet. I always get the exception from StripeEventUtility.ConstructEvent method.
The WebHook key is correct, the Request Header contains "Stripe-Signature" keys.

I correctly receive incoming data from the Webhook tester utility (using nGrok with Visual Studio).

I tried to manipulate the incoming data from Stripe (Jobject, string, serializing...). The payload signature may cause some problem.

Has anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Webhook tester utility

Are you referring to the Stripe CLI, using the `listen` command and forwarding to your endpoint? If so, it's important that you use the webhook secret returned by the `listen` command, and not one related to a configured endpoint on your Dashboard.

The other main source of this issue is mutation of the request body. Signature verification depends strictly on having access to the raw body of the request, including original whitespace etc.

See this sample implementation of a webhook endpoint in .NET accessing the raw request body: https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-payment/blob/main/custom-payment-flow/server/dotnet/Controllers/PaymentsController.cs#L86